# ERROR: could not insert module When load driver module on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When i want to load driver module of [Wo Mic](http://www.wirelessorange.com/womic/)  on `Ubuntu 14.04` i get this error in `Terminal` :

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module wo_snd_capture-x86_64.ko: Invalid parameters
```

I follow the Wo Mic instruction for load module like the official website of Wo Mic.

In Wo Mic Official websit :

> Change client program to be executable
>
> `$ chmod a+x micclient-ubuntu-x86_64`
>
> Load driver module
>
> `$ sudo insmod wo_snd_capture-x86_64.ko`

But when i enter this `sudo insmod wo_snd_capture-x86_64.ko` in Terminal i get above Error .

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because wo_snd_capture-x86_64.ko module was compiled for different kernel version than yours.

```
$ modinfo ./wo_snd_capture-x86_64.ko 
filename:       .../wo_snd_capture-x86_64.ko
license:        GPL
srcversion:     E535A4C547FF773D30C0B16
depends:        snd-pcm,snd
vermagic:       4.4.0-62-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Note that version in vermagic. You can check your kernel version with uname -a. Your version is different.

As you can see, it is GPL licenced, so just ask authors of this module for source code and you will be able to recompile this module by yourself every time you upgrade your kernel.